# Eigenvalues of a nilpotent matrix can only be $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Prove that the eigenvalues for a square Nilpotent matrix *A* can only be $0$.

Definition of nilpotent

> *A* $^n$=$0$

*n* is a positive whole integer

Comment: I was about to add a disclosure about that, thanks hardmath

Comment: @Behaviour : yes, this is actually a duplicate of it, looks like my search wasn't extensive enough.

Comment: No problem. By the way, your question here... lacked a question. Please consider the advice in [How to ask a Good Question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959)

Comment: @Behaviour et al: perhaps this is merely a grammatical curiosity, but the question cited as a possible duplicate is in fact only a question insofar as the title is an imperative sentence followed by a question mark!  Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can also work directly, without the apparatus of the minimal polynomial:

If $V$ is a vector space over the field $\Bbb F$, then by definition an eigenvalue satisfies

$Ax = \lambda x, \; \;, 0 \ne x \in V; \lambda \in \Bbb F, \tag{1}$

then

$A^2 x = A(Ax) = A(\lambda x) = \lambda (Ax) = \lambda^2 x, \tag{2}$

and so if we assume

$A^k x = \lambda^k x \tag{3}$

then we have

$A^{k + 1} x = A(A^k x) = A(\lambda^k x) = \lambda^k Ax = \lambda^{k + 1} x; \tag{4}$

taking (1)-(2) as base cases, we have thus completed a simple inductive proof that

$A^n x = \lambda^n x \tag{5}$

for all integers $n \ge 1$.  Now if

$A^n = 0, \tag{6}$

then an eigenvalue $\lambda$, satisftying (1), also satisfies

$\lambda^n x = A^n x = 0, \tag{7}$

and since $x \ne 0$ we must have

$\lambda^n = 0, \tag{8}$

whence

$\lambda = 0. \tag{9}$.

***QED.***

In response to FemptoComm's comment to Timbuc's answer, the chances are diminished by the fact that nonzero nilpotent matrices $A$ are *can't* be diagonalized, and that $\det A = 0$ only allows us to conclude that *some* eigenvalue is zero, not *all* eigenvalues.  I leave the proofs of these well-known facts to may readers.

Disclaimer:  I read Timbuc's comment to his own answer *after* writing this up.

Hope this helps.  Holiday Cheers,

and as ever,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: The upvote on this answer put me over 15K.  Thanks, whoever.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$A^n=0\implies A\;\;\text{is a root of}\;\;x^n\implies\;\text{its minimal polynomial divides}\;\;x^n$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, is there a chance you could deduce this using diagonalization and determinants?

Comment: @FemtoComm For diagonalization one can use the minimal polynomial, and the *only* diagonal nilpotent matrix is the zero matrix. Another way: for a scalar $\;\lambda\;$ we have that $$Av=\lambda v\implies A^kv=\lambda^kv=0\;,\;\;\forall\,k\in\Bbb N$$ so $$0=A^nv=\lambda^nv\implies \lambda^n=0\iff \lambda =0 $$

Comment: @Timbuc I think that your comment is the better answer because it uses directly the properties given and doesn't rely on a more general theorem.